# Calculate cumulative prevalence of carriage of resistant bugs

Tags: r, variables, encode, new-operator

I have recently started using R. When working on carriage of problematic bacteria, I encountered one problem that I hope somebody could help solve. Apologies if the question is on the easy side.

I want to calculate the cumulative proportion of people who get colonized by the problem bug at various time points (a, b, c) as shown in the dataset below "df". "0" means negative test, "1" means positive test for resistant bug, "NA" means test was not done at the time point. The result should be as described in "x", i.e. if the person ever tests positive on either time point (a,b,c) he should have the value "1" in x. If all his tests were negative he should have value "0", and if he never had a test done, the value should be "NA". Is there a good way to calculate this "x" automatically?

```
a <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, NA, NA)
b <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, NA, 0, 0, NA, 0)
c <- c(NA, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, NA, 0)
df <- cbind(a, b, c)
df

x <- c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0,NA,0)
df <- cbind(df, x)
df
```

I tried to create the x-variable using ifelse, but get problems with missing values. For instance, using the following expression:

```
y <- ifelse(a==1 | b==1 | c==1, 1, ifelse(a==0 | b==0 | c==0, 0, NA))
df <- cbind(df, y)
df
```

... the resultant column erroneously get "NA" in row 1 and 10, i.e. when there is a combination of 0 and NA, the result should be 0, not NA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `rowSums` :

```
cols <- c('a', 'b', 'c')
+(rowSums(df[, cols], na.rm = TRUE) > 0) * NA^+(rowSums(!is.na(df[, cols])) == 0)
#[1]  0  1  1  0  1  1  1  0 NA  0
```

This gives similar result as `x` shown however, might be difficult to understand.

---

Here is a simple alternative using `apply` :

```
apply(df[, cols], 1, function(x) if(all(is.na(x))) NA else +(any(x == 1, na.rm = TRUE)))
#[1]  0  1  1  0  1  1  1  0 NA  0
```

This returns `NA` if all the values in the row are `NA` else checks if `any` value has 1 in it.

Comment: Thank you so much, Ronak. Both of these work very nicely.

Comment: Thank you so much, Ronak. Both of these work very nicely. I wonder how I could apply this calculation in a bigger dataset. I.e. columns a, b and c are part of a big database with hundreds of columns and rows. How could one create a column x in this database based on performing this calculation on columns a, b and c? In Stata I would use something like this " generate x=." then "replace x = 0 if a==0 | b==0 | c==0" , then "replace x = 1 if a==1 | b==1 | c==1 ", but I cannot find out how to code this in R, yet... Your methods seem very elegant, but I struggle to integrate this in the database?

Comment: @BjornBlomberg See the updated answer in which I apply the answer  only on 'a', 'b' and 'c' columns.

Comment: Thank you so much, again, Ronak. This is so helpful! Wishing you a great day!

Comment: Eventually, I found another way to solve it within the main database It is not as elegant as yours, but somehow easy to understand.  Thanks again!
    df$x <- df$a
    df$x[df$a==0] <- 0
    df$x[df$b==0] <- 0
    df$x[df$c==0] <- 0
    df$x[df$a==1] <- 1
    df$x[df$b==1] <- 1
    df$x[df$c==1] <- 1